# Automatically set width and height in editText

Tags: android

I am creating a draggable EditText on android. I put my editText on a Relative layout and my problem is everytime I input a long text it goes to second line even though it is not filled in the relative layout.

This is my sample layout:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    |
|             +----------------+                     |
|             | This is my text|                     |
|             | in editText    |                     |
|             +----------------+                     |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    |
|             +----------------------------+         |
|             | This is my text in editText|         |
|             +----------------------------+         |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to wrap first my text in the whole layout (width) before going to second line.

This is my code:

```
 class AddTextTouchListener implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.imgstage);
      Context context = getApplicationContext();
      EditText imv=new EditText(context);
      imv.setText("Sample");
      imv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      imv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
      imv.setCursorVisible(false);
      imv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
      imv.setOnLongClickListener(new longClickTextListener());
      imv.setEms(10);
      imv.setMaxLines(4);
      imv.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
      LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      imv.setLayoutParams(params);
      layout.addView(imv);

    }
}
```

this is my longClickListener to able to drag editText:

```
class longClickTextListener implements OnLongClickListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lastImageSelected = view;

        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: why you are creating layout in java code why not in layout file. Is that your requirement?

Comment: Yes, I am creating editText dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion here would be to calculate how much space you have to the right of the screen from where the edit text is being placed, then set that as the width of the edit text.

So, for example, you'd want to do something like this:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(screenWidth - editTextLeftMargin, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will solve after creating the text, but what if I edit it to a bigger/longer text?

Comment: This will make the edit text extend to the entire width of the screen. Since the background of the edit text is transparent, it shouldn't interfere with the UI. You won't need to change the size after this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting

```
imv.setEms(10); //this sets the width of the EditText remove it
```

Try getting rid of this line, because it tells the layout how wide it wants to be. You want it to be dynamic, and this is restricting it.

This would also be easier if you were using an XML file. I suggest building the same thing in XML layout file and finding what settings the EditText needs to pull off what you want before creating it dynamically (just because layout files make it easy to drag stuff around).

Comment: I also want to have more than 1 line if the width of the text is longer than the layout. That is the time when there will be 2 lines.

Comment: @MMakati Ah, I thought you might have meant that instead. What I had was incorrect, I changed my answer with something that should help.

Comment: I removed the `setEms()` but still the same. Does editText have listener that detects if the user is done editing.

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas, but yes EditText does have a listener. Look at `setOnEditorActionListener` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener(android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener)